# how to configure psql to use the a different unixsocket path

Tags: postgresql, psql

I changed the port of Postgres to `2345` and I have the socket in:

```
/tmp/.s.PGSQL.2345
```

If I run `psql` I get this error:

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
```

how to pass the socket path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `-p` option

```bash
psql -p 2345
```

Comment: that works but is using TCP or the socket?

Comment: since you don't provide a host `--host=..` psql uses its predefined socket directory by default. which is /tmp in rhel / centos etc